# Android Bluetooth code crashes

Tags: android, crash, bluetooth

I have been trying to get the Android developers bluetooth example code
( http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html )
to work reliably but unfortunately it keeps crashing after the socket closes 50 or even up to 1000 times.

A SPP BT module (HC-06) is used that is shut down every minute to reproduce the problem. 
The weird thing is that when it crashes the pairing is lost and you have to re-enter the pin number. I use a timer to reconnect after the socket closes. Also tried without a timer and used a "new ConnectThread(device).start()" in the IOException handler.

Posting the code is not much use because I use the same code as the Android developers example.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Android version: 4.1.1 and 4.2.2

Comment: what does the error message say?

Comment: Is it a crash or a normal exception (that you're not catching) occurring when the socket closes?

Comment: the eror message says "app has stopped working"

Comment: the bluetooth environment crashes and the pairing is lost.

Comment: this issue was solved by using a master bluetooth module (HC-05) instead of the slave (HC-06)